# How to place the QED symbol at the end of equation using IEEEproof environment?

Tags: equations, amsmath, ieeetran

I was wondering how one can place the QED symbol at the end of an equation when using the `IEEEproof` environment?

With the standard `proof` environment of `amsthm` this is done by simply placing `\qedhere` at the end of the equation, for example:

```
\begin{equation}
     x = y+z \qedhere
\end{equation}
```

But the same code does not work when we change the environment to `IEEEproof`. In this case the QED symbol will be placed at the end of next line.

Comment: `amsmath` does not provide a `proof` environment; that is provided by `amsthm`.  the mechanism for `qedhere` is rather complicated, and depends on coordination between `amsthm` and `amsmath`.  it is probably possible to patch `IEEEproof` to enable `\qedhere` to work, but without access to `ieeetran.cls` (it's not on ctan), i'll leave that to someone else.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will correct my question. Indeed, I thought there should be something similar to `\qedhere` also in `ieeetran.cls`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

The `IEEEtran` documentclass does have its own versions of `\qedhere` namely `\IEEEQEDhereeqn` for use in equations and `\IEEEQEDhere` for `eqnarray` and other enviroments, e.g. lists (thank you to Aditya for noting the latter).  Here is a demonstration:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
  Ordinary case.
\end{theorem}

\begin{IEEEproof}
  That's it!
\end{IEEEproof}

\begin{theorem}
  A statement.
\end{theorem}

\begin{IEEEproof}
  We see
  \begin{equation}
    x=y \IEEEQEDhereeqn\quad
  \end{equation}
\end{IEEEproof}

\begin{theorem}
  Another statement.
\end{theorem}

\begin{IEEEproof}
  We consider the following points:
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item assumptions,
  \item implications. \hspace{1em plus 1fill}\IEEEQEDhere
  \end{enumerate}
\end{IEEEproof}

\begin{theorem}
  Final statement.
\end{theorem}

\begin{IEEEproof}
  We compute
  \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    1 + 2 & = & 2 + 1 \IEEEnonumber\\
    & = & 3.
    \qquad\IEEEQEDhere
  \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{IEEEproof}

\begin{IEEEproof}[Alternative proof.]
  We compute
  \begin{equation}
    \begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}{rCl}
    1 + 2 & = & 2 + 1 \\
    & = & 3.
  \end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
  \IEEEQEDhereeqn\quad
\end{equation}
\end{IEEEproof}

\end{document}
```

Note the spacing.  For the equation version you need add some space afterwards otherwise it will be right up against the equation number.  I have chose `\quad` but another possibility is `\`.  In the other cases you see that `\IEEEQEDhere` does not place the symbol at the right-hand margin without help.  I have shown how to this in an `enumerate`.  For the `IEEEeqnarray` it is does not seem to be possible, but I give a work around, placing it inside an `equation`, in the case when you only want one equation number.

Comment: `IEEEQEDhere` is meant to manually place the QED symbol if a proof ends with an enumeration, etc.

Comment: @Aditya Many thanks - I have now substantially updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is inteded as a comment to Andrew Swann's answer, but I don't have enough reputation to post a comment - apologies.

Andrew Swann provides a workaround to get `\qedhere` to work nicely in `IEEEeqnarray`: use a nested `equation` environment.

There is another workaround - explicitly define a column for the QED symbol.  For example:

```
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{+rCl+x*}
a & = & b + c \\
& = & d + e. & \qedhere
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
```

This is described in more detail on page 60 of "The not so sort introduction to LaTeX 2e" (https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort-a5.pdf).